# geojson to maps using Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, gis, geojson

I have been trying to project my geojson data onto a map. Which is when i came across this doc from google.

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/datalayer
```

Can someone who has worked with google maps API explain me the meaning of this code segment:

```
// Load a GeoJSON from the same server as our demo.
  map.data.loadGeoJson('https://storage.googleapis.com/maps-devrel/google.json');
```

What do they mean by "Load a GeoJSON from the same server as our demo.". My geojson file is in my local drive(C:). How can i modify the code so that my json file is loaded?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are loading your HTML file with a `file://`-URL, eg. `file:///C:/myfile.html`, you should be able to use `map.data.loadGeoJson('file:///C:/mydata.json')`.

However, keep in mind that this only works as long as you are loading both your HTML/Javascript and the data from the same origin due to the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy).

Since the ToS do not allow you to host the API scripts yourself, you might have to setup a local webserver for testing. You can then control cross-origin access by setting the [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) HTTP header.

Comment: hi, both my html+js and json files are on the desktop. So used the loadGeoJson as suggested by u, which is as follows:                                                                                    // Load a GeoJSON from the same server as our demo.
 map.data.loadGeoJson('file:///C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/test.             json');                                                                  I still do not see the polygons drawn on the map. Pls help. Can provide more details if you want.

Comment: does same-origin policy mean that I have json files stored in the same domain where i'm accessing google api's from?

Comment: you probably wont get around using a http server + CORS headers -> I extended my answer a bit.